# Vertical align text in Bootstrap 4 divs (with btn class) with no fixed height when using CSS Grid (and no flexbox)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid with Bootstrap 4 divs with `btn` tags in it. The divs widen (stretch) vertically. I just need to vertical align text in the middle.

I know I can use flexbox but in this project I can't.

[image]

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fredhors/0sw2uLay/5/

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vmax, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-primary">Content A</div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning">Content B</div>
  <div class="btn btn-danger">Content C</div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">Content D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, @kukkuz, because I loose the 100% height of each one.

Comment: I have used *pseudo elements* to the center the text - that keeps the 100% height of the *grid items*...

Answer (score 1):

If you have to center the whole `btn`, just use `align-items: center` on the `grid-wrapper` - see demo below:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vmax, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-primary">Content A</div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning">Content B</div>
  <div class="btn btn-danger">Content C</div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">Content D</div>
</div>
```

If you want the background *stretched* and have the *vertical alignment*, its easier if you should use flexbox for `btn` - see demo below:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vmax, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-wrapper > .btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-primary">Content A</div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning">Content B</div>
  <div class="btn btn-danger">Content C</div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">Content D</div>
</div>
```

---

> I know I can use flexbox but in this project I can't.

If you can't use flexbox for this, you can use a *pseudo element* that will center the text in the *grid items* - see demo below:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20vmax, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-wrapper .btn:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-primary">Content A</div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning">Content B</div>
  <div class="btn btn-danger">Content C</div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">Content D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @kukkuz. Can I ask you what is the best in terms of performances if I have a huge list (thousands of divs)? Flexbox or the pseudo element? (Chrome, Safari).

Comment: I would normally use flexbox as it is easy and well-supported in modern browsers... I'm not sure of performance though

Comment: Do you think I can test it somewhere on the web?

Comment: I guess if there are thousands of divs that would not be a good user experience design ;)